# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.animation.Animation android.view.View.getAnimation()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio

when I click on it it open a java file which is only readable how to solve this issue this is run time exception first time app works fine second time app crash i don't know why any guidelines
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.animation.Animation android.view.View.getAnimation()' on a null object reference
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.addDisap
pearingFragmentView(FragmentContainerView.java:362)

i dont find line in androidstudio any one can tell ,e that how to find the place of run time exception called

Answer (score 0):

Please do add Code where you are getting such errors.

Comment: i dont know why it shows error because some time it will become main screen and some time any other layout but dont know where is this any idea how to find it ?

Comment: You might not have initialized animation view.
For ex: if you added a button in XML with id = button and you will initialize it in java class as `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); `
Similarly there is a view which you haven't initialized but you trying to use it.